# Pass int[] to AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I having a problem to pass an int-array to a class that extends AsyncTask.

The int-array consists of resourceId's for bitmap images.

```
final int[] resIdImage =  resId_image;
```

and I send this vector through:

```
execute(resIdImage);
```

And the class that extends AsyncTask

```
static class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask <int[], Void, Bitmap[]>
   private int[] data = new int[9];
```

and the doInBackground which recieves these resourceIds through *params*

```
@Override
protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(int[] ... params) {

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = params[i];
}
```

But I got the following error int the doInBackGround-method:

**Type missmatch: cannot convert from int[] to int**

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you use static class?

Comment: data[i] = params[i];   <--- doesnt work like that

Comment: the class that extends AsyncTask is a static inner class. To avoid memoryleak it has to be static.

Comment: @bofredo : why not ? depends on how data is defined in the first place

Comment: @user2365568 : by the way, please post the declaration and definition of your data variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`params[0]` here refers to `int[]`. So you can do the following.

```
@Override
protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(int[] ... params) {

int[] data=params[0];
```

Comment: I would tend to agree to this answer. I would like to know a bit more about this `data` variable before upvoting, though.

Comment: it's an int array. exactly the same type as 'resIdImage' and references to the same memory location which 'resIdImage' references to.

Answer (score 1):

to pull out the array you need to do

```
int[] data = params[0];
```

then you can do your loop